# Minimal Spark session/configuration for optimal unit test performance?

Tags: performance, unit-testing, apache-spark

Spark 2.1.0 and Scala 2.11.

Our project has hundreds of unit tests that perform relatively simple operations such as creating data sets of 3 or 4 objects and performing simple transformations on them.  Many of these tests take as long as 5-10 seconds to run, which with hundreds of tests adds up to many minutes and is becoming a problem for our CI build.  The operations are so simple that I wonder if there is a Spark configuration we can use to speed things up.

For example simply creating a data set like this:

```
val histData = Seq(
  FooType(id = "id1", code = "code1",orgId = 1l),
  FooType(id = "id2", code = "code2",orgId = 1l),
  FooType(id = "id3", code = "code3",orgId = 1l)
).toDS()
```

takes 800 msec (FooType is a case class).  After creating 2 or 3 data sets like this and a few filter / map / join operations (I really don't think those details matter but if you do let me know and I will post them), the `collect()` takes 1000-2000 msec.  Add up a few operations like this and a test can take 5-10 seconds.

For the unit tests we are only concerned with the functional aspects of the test, we do not need threading, scaling, cacheing, on-disk storage, etc.  The test data is small (usually less than 1KB) and is created in memory (not read from disk or any external source), and assertions are performed on the transformed objects in memory.  I understand that behind the scenes Spark may be invoking the DAGScheduler, code generator, etc. and I wonder if there is a way to execute the jobs without that functionality.  Or if that does have to be done, to do it once at the start of the unit test suite and use that throughout.

The session is created with something like this:

```
session = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions","10").getOrCreate()
```

and the same session is used in each unit test.  We are invoking the Spark API methods directly from the unit test, so there is no Spark submit or separate process or job, it all runs in the JVM created by either the IDE or gradle that invokes the unit tests.

It just seems to me that these operations should be taking a few msec each, and I'm looking for a way to pare down the Spark configuration so it evaluates everything in memory in the fastest way possible.  Thanks for any tips or ideas.

Comment: Did you  tried unit testing multiple files with this approach ?

Answer (score 2):

From my personal experience using Scala.

1. Create a test wrapper object

```scala
object SparkSessionTestWrapper {
  lazy val spark: SparkSession = {
    SparkSession.builder()
      .appName("Unit Test")
      .master("local[*]")
      .getOrCreate()
  }
}
```

A good way to optimize performance is disabling the UI while creating your spark session

```scala
object SparkSessionTestWrapper {
  lazy val spark: SparkSession = {
    SparkSession.builder()
      .appName("Unit Test")
      .master("local[*]")
      .config("spark.ui.enabled", "false")  
      .getOrCreate()
  }
}
```

The lazy val spark ensures that the spark session is created only once and is used.

2. Then in each of your UT classes call the SparkSessionTestWrapper, it will use the same "shared" spark session so no need to create one for each UT:

```scala
class UnitTest1 {
  import SparkSessionTestWrapper._

  test("Test case 1") {
    import spark.implicits._

    val histData = Seq(
      FooType(id = "id1", code = "code1",orgId = 1l),
      FooType(id = "id2", code = "code2",orgId = 1l),
      FooType(id = "id3", code = "code1",orgId = 1l)
    ).toDS()

    val result = histData.filter($"orgId " === 1l).select("code").distinct().collect()

    assert(result.length == 2)
    //other assertions ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your default parallelism to 1, that will dramatically improve performance

Then try with 1 executor, that'll help keep the cpu cache hot

Then you can run tests in parallel, a spark session is thread safe. Don't forget to allocate more executors then!